# Fill all available stack with specific value

Tags: android, c++, arm

I need to fill all available stack space with specific character for profiling purposes.

First of all, is there a safe way to do this on Android(some compiler specific functions maybe) in C++? If not, may I assume the address of first variable declared in a function is the "start" of "unused" stack? If not is there a way to get current stack pointer, something like ESP value on x86?

Comment: Actually, after looking I thin that [How to determine Stack size of a Program in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678803/how-to-determine-stack-size-of-a-program-in-linux) has an answer, by [Steven Schlansker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/171061/steven-schlansker), to your exact question.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by all available stack space? Per some specific functions, all functions? all program space? Multi-threaded? more generally http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/195751

Comment: @auselen When creating a new thread in the entry point function I want to fill all stack with special value to be able to detect later how much of the stack was used.

Comment: Did you check stack-protector stuff? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: @auselen I need to know stack usage to be able to set stack size as low as possible to reduce memory usage.

Comment: GCC has an option for that too :) `-fstack-usage` however I hope you can imagine it is hard to calculate total stack usage on a runtime.

Comment: @auselen I need just some statistics/estimations. The statistics have to be made on many platforms. Using compiler specific features is not an option. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ARM, you need to think about calling convention since a function with more than four arguments would have them spilled to stack. I find it much safer to use [GCC's __builtin_frame_address.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html)

```
Built-in Function: void * __builtin_frame_address (unsigned int level)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this functions is not available for Android:|

Comment: @Felics That's a builtin GCC function, it should be in NDK toolchain as well. Btw I just verified it works with NDK r9b.

Comment: On Android(arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 toolchain) it's missing...

Comment: @Felics Can't be. Can you post the error message?

Comment: I'm sooooo noob:) I had one i in the functions name. Thanks!!